# sql server 2000: release lock on table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I run the following query

select * from my t1 where c1 = 22

and query runs for ever.. How can I find out whats locking that row?

I tried runnning sp_who, sp_who2, sp_lock, and googled for information but still no resolution in sight.

Please help.

I am using sql server 2000.

Comment: Are you sure something's locking that row?  What did sp_who2 tell you about that?

Comment: What was the output of the sp_who, sp_who2, sp_lock?

Comment: sp_who2 returns whole bunch of rows.. I dont know how to identify what is locking this table

Comment: I did invoke a KILL on blk value returned from sp_who call like KILL 111 but the row is still locked.

Comment: I do not know how to translate sp_lock output..I looked at some explanation but there is none that simply shows how to identify the issue and resolve it quickly.

Comment: I do get one row back when I run this..
select * from sysprocesses where blocked > 0
but I still do not know how to identify who is locking and how to unlock..

Comment: Is it possible that you restart SQL Server? Brutal, but works ;-)

Comment: I am trying to determine how to remove the lock on that particular row...

Answer (score 1):

You look at `blocked`, `waittype`, `waittime` and `waitresource` on [`sysprocesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260456(SQL.80).aspx).